# ECW on QGIS 1.8 (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to deal with an ECW file with QuantumGis 1.8 Lisboa, on Ubuntu 11.10. Obviously it tells me that .ecw is not a supported kind of file on QuantumGis. I have tried to install all the libraries but it still doesn't work.

What sould I do?

Thanks,

Jacopo

Comment: It works fine on Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

Download the libecwj 3.3 [source](https://build.opensuse.org/package/files?package=libecwj&project=home%3ajluce2%3aGEO) and compile that. Then follow the UbuntuGIS ECW (libgdal-ecw-src) [Tutorial](http://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/UserTutorials)

Note that the 3.3 ECW SDK is very old, but there is no support for linux in the current (4.2) version. [Apparently](http://field-guide.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/update-on-erdas-ecwjp2-sdk-v50.html) linux will be supported in the v.5.0 SDK.

Step by step instructions...

```
#Get libecwj 3.3 (the old SDK), it's available from a number of sources. 
# If the link below doesn't work, google for "libecwj2-3.3"
wget -nd https://api.opensuse.org/public/source/home:jluce2:GEO/libecwj/libecwj2-3.3.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf libecwj2-3.3.tar.bz2
cd libecwj2-3.3
./configure
make
sudo make install

#Install the gdal ecw plugin source package and build it 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable && sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libgdal-ecw-src build-essential 
sudo gdal-ecw-build /usr/local 
sudo ldconfig #this step is missing from UbuntuGIS tutorial

#Try it out
gdalinfo --formats|grep -i ecw
  ECW (rw): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 3.x)
  JP2ECW (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 3.x)
```

Comment: The UbuntuGISECW tutorial doesn't work

Comment: Worked fine for me (though that was on Ubuntu 10.04). Did you compile and install libecwj 3.3? I am talking about the ERDAS (then ER Mapper) SDK from the link in my answer, NOT the libgdal-ecw-src package provided by UbuntuGIS which is simply a plugin that lets GDAL talk to the ERDAS SDK.  By the way, saying "it doesn't work" is very unhelpful...

Comment: I just installed successfully on Ubuntu 12.04 so it does work.

Comment: I had to add an environment variable into /etc/environment GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=/usr/lib/gdalplugins/1.9

Answer (score 1):

Nathan tells us how;
http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/getting-ecw-and-mrsid-support-working-in-qgis-dev-osgeo4w-install/

this works for me as of yesterday on 1.8 production Win7

Comment: I tried to go to the packages manager: when I manage to check libgdal-ecw-src it tells me that

*This change is not coming from a source that supports changelogs.
Failed to fetch the changelog for libgdal-ecw-src
URI was: http://ppa.launchpad.net/pool/main/libg/libgdal-ecw/libgdal-ecw-src_1.9.1-2~oneiric3_all.changelog*

What should I do?

Comment: ps: the ESRI link doesn't work well on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an issue with your gdal-ecw-build script. 
My system:

- LinuxMint 12 (based on Ubuntu 11 oneiric)
- package source: standard deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted universe multiverse . On this installed using ubuntu package manager:
- qgis 1.8.0.1~oneiric1
- libgdal-ecw-src 1.9.1-2~oneiric3

ERmapper libecwj2-3.3 compiled and installed fine as per above instructions, but the GDAL-ECW-BUILD script crashes because it expects (at least on my system) the libgdal-ecw-src tarball to be in the ***gz***ip format, whereas it actually is a plain tar. If running the script on your system crashes with a message like:

```
Extracting GDAL/ECW tarball
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Building GDAL/ECW plugin
cd: 70: can't cd to /tmp/gdal-ecw-build.fCIAbO/libgdal-ecw-1.9.1
```

then open the /usr/bin/gdal-ecw-build script in your text editor (as root), scroll down to around line 59 where you may see:

```
echo "Extracting GDAL/ECW tarball" 
tar xzf $TARBALL -C $BUILDDIR
```

Change the second line to read:

```
echo "Extracting GDAL/ECW tarball" 
tar xf $TARBALL -C $BUILDDIR
```

Save, rerun the script and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal blog there are two posts, "[Adding ECW support to GDAL via plugins](http://ariasprado.name/2011/02/27/gdal-ecw-support-via-plugins.html)" and "[Revisiting ECW support to GDAL via plugins: a patch.](http://ariasprado.name/2012/05/02/revisiting-ecw-support-to-gdal-via-plugins-a-patch.html)" that you might help you despite the described procedures are cumbersome.

These blog posts are recipes to add to the GDAL library limited support for the ECW format. Once this is achived, QGIS should be able to read ECW files.

Comment: The links are dead.