# How to use ECWP protocol with QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to retrieve remote data through ECWP protocol in QGIS? I've read that .ecw files can be opened with QGIS, but haven't found anything concerning this particular protocol and QGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the ERDAS ECW/JP2 SDK and the GDAL ECW plugin [installed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29281/ecw-on-qgis-1-8-ubuntu-11-10). Then use a [VRT](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) to point to the ECWP Raster. You can then load the vrt into QGIS like a standard filesystem raster.  An easy way of generating the vrt file, is to use [gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html).

i.e.

```
gdalbuildvrt ecwpraster.vrt ecwp://myimagewebserver/folder/file.ecw
```

Which creates vrt a file containing:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="500880" rasterYSize="409335">
  <GeoTransform> 8.7132999999999963e+006, 2.5000000000000000e+000, 0.0000000000000000e+000, 5.0460199999999991e+006, 0.0000000000000000e+000,-2.5000000000000000e+000</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
    <ColorInterp>Red</ColorInterp>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">ecwp://myimagewebserver/folder/file.ecw</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="500880" RasterYSize="409335" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="500880" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="500880" ySize="409335" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="500880" ySize="409335" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="2">
    <ColorInterp>Green</ColorInterp>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">ecwp://myimagewebserver/folder/file.ecw</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>2</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="500880" RasterYSize="409335" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="500880" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="500880" ySize="409335" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="500880" ySize="409335" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="3">
    <ColorInterp>Blue</ColorInterp>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">ecwp://myimagewebserver/folder/file.ecw</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>3</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="500880" RasterYSize="409335" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="500880" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="500880" ySize="409335" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="500880" ySize="409335" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

Comment: I know that it's a very old thread but finally I've managed to add this .ecw layer throgh ecwp:// protocol. I've built the .vrt file with the built-in GdalTools of QGIS. Thank you for your help.